# How to use htaccess for wordpress on root and codeigniter in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have following directory structure

-testmywork (ROOT)
---admin *(CONTAIN CODEIGNITER FRAMEWORK)*
---cgi-bin
---wp *(CONTAIN WORDPRESS)*
---htaccess

Now here, my admin folder contain codeigniter framework and my root has wp folder. when my root is accessed, it goes to wp folder and when i access testmywork/admin, it opens the login screen but once i put admin username and password, it goes back to my main root and shows page not found error but instead this it should open my codeigniter framwork i.e it should go to admin panel's dashboard after successful login.

What should i do? Should i change my htaccess code? If yes, then how to do that?

Comment: have you set the CodeIgniter `base_url` config to `testmywork/admin` ?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/admin';

Comment: where did the login controller redirect to after login? Could you show the redirects line on the login controller?

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, It redirect to dashboard, this is the redirect code.....   redirect('dashboard');

Comment: Try to use `site_url()` : `redirect( site_url('dashboard' ) );`